# Validation still applies when input field is empty and counts it wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, passwords

I have a password field that I want to validate on 3 conditions. When I match all criteria it skips one strength: **weak**.

When I empty the input field one regex expression still matches the criteria and I don't know why.

It skips the weak strength and when you remove everything. The strength stays on bad but it should go to empty. Any suggestions what is wrong or how i can improve it? thanks in advance

This is my HTML:

```
<label class="customer__form-field js-cm-field">
                        <span>{{'form.password' | trans}} *</span>
                        <input type="password"
                               name="password"
                               required>
                    </label>
                    <div class="password-strength progress js-cm-password-strength" data-passwordstrength="empty">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar">
                            Strength
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="password-tips">
                        <li class="letters" data-letters="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            lower and uppercase letters
                            Kleine letters en hoofdletters.
                        </li>
                        <li class="numbers" data-numbers="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            letters and numbers
                            Letters en cijfers.
                        </li>
                        <li class="characters" data-characters="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            special characters
                            Speciale characters
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

This is my JS

```
var validation_message = "";
function returnError () {
    return validation_message;
};

// Password validation
$.validator.addMethod("password", function(value) {
  var strength = {
        0: "empty",
        1: "bad",
        2: "weak",
        3: "strong"
    };
    var score = 0;
    // If password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value.
    if (value.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) {
         score += 1;
        $('.letters').attr('data-letters', "true");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    } else {
        score -= 1;
        $('.letters').attr('data-letters', "false");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    }
    // // // If it has numbers and characters, increase strength value.
    if (value.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && value.match(/([0-9])/)) {
        score += 1;
        $('.numbers').attr('data-numbers', "true");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    } else {
        score -= 1;
        $('.numbers').attr('data-numbers', "false");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    }
    // // // If it has one special character, increase strength value.
    if (value.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
        score += 1;
        $('.characters').attr('data-characters', "true");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    } else {
        score -= 1;
        $('.characters').attr('data-characters', "false");
        $('.js-cm-password-strength').attr('data-passwordstrength', strength[score]);
    }

    if(score < 1) {
        validation_message = "Het wachtwoord is te zwak kijk bij de tips om het wachtwoord sterker te maken.";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, returnError);
```

The rules for jQuery validate
http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
        rules: {
            password: {
                password: true
            },
        }
```

Comment: Try changing `score < 1` to `score < 0`

Comment: @Lublaut doesnt help

Comment: What is your condition for *empty*?

Comment: @Lublaut that is the problem I tried value.length, null, "" etc.  it doesn't matter what i use. it doesnt decrease the score

Comment: Are you saying that whatever you do the strength is always bad? even for strong and weak?

Comment: @Lublaut I goes like this: when you are at the form, the data attribute is empty. I fill in a password that matches 1 criteria. For example aaaaaA (lower and uppercase). Now it becomes bad.  I add a number aaaaaaA$ (Character criteria) it accepts it but the strength is still bad. When i add a number aaaaaaA$1 (number criteria). It goes to the strength good. So it skips weak.

When i remove everything, empty input field. It doesn't reset propperly. So i still match all criterias. When i put a letter "a" in again. It resets, it should reset when it is empty.

Comment: The second criteria fails because the second condition fails.... Try eliminating all the *else* part and also change *score < 1* to *score < 0*.

Comment: @Lublaut When i fill in the values for the second criteria: it excecutes : $('.numbers').attr('data-numbers', "true");  How can it than be wrong?

Comment: the second condition is false for the example *aaaaaaaaaaaA$*

Comment: @Lublaut So it should be it contains a number & letter instead of only. Because the $ is a character and it makes the condition false.

Comment: @Lublaut i got this part working, without the else it wont reset the data attributes. So the score stays good. It won't go down